# image disappears when wrapped inside expo Router Link

Tags: react-native, expo-router

i am currently using expo router in my project. i have wrapped an image component inside a link tag . this causes the image to disappear, kindly assist on how to fix this.

```
  <Link href={`${pathname}/screen1/screen2`}>
    <Pressable onPress={toDetails}>
    <View style={styles.postImageView}>
      <Image style={styles.postImage} source={{ uri: postDisplayImage }} />
    </View>
    </Pressable>
  </Link>
```

i wanted the image to be a pressable link

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today and the issue was with my styles so maybe the same thing is happening to you. For testing purposes, does anything show up if you just do this?

```
<Link href={`${pathname}/screen1/screen2`}>
  <Pressable onPress={toDetails}>
    <View>
      <Image source={{ uri: postDisplayImage }} />
    </View>
  </Pressable>
</Link>
```

Comment: its the styles that had issue. i was using aspect ratio for image properties but apparently you have to specify the width and height px

Answer (score 0):

Images don't work great inside expo Links by default because the contents are wrapped inside `Text` component (reference to the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/routing/navigating-pages/#buttons)).

You can avoid that behavior by using the `asChild` attribute. Remember to use a `<Pressable>` component as first child, which you are already doing.

```
  <Link href={`${pathname}/screen1/screen2`} asChild>
    <Pressable onPress={toDetails}>
      <View style={styles.postImageView}>
        <Image style={styles.postImage} source={{ uri: postDisplayImage }} />
      </View>
    </Pressable>
  </Link>
```